# compilation.mainTemplate.hooks in webpack5

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I have a webpack4 compatible webpack plugin that I am trying to make compatible with webpack5. I see 3 hooks in the code that I cannot find documentation for

```
compilation.mainTemplate.hooks.jsonpScript
compilation.mainTemplate.hooks.requireEnsure
compilation.mainTemplate.hooks.requireExtensions
```

The webpack documentation mentions that compilation.mainTemplate is being deprecated but can still be used, but there is no documentation about these hooks or what their purpose is.

Where can I find more details about these and what is the right way to move these to webpack5 compatible plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: I found the documentation for jsonpScript and requireEnsure here in the webpack internal plugins. https://v4.webpack.js.org/plugins/internal-plugins/.

Still looking for requireExtensions